# Haaaaaaaaaaaats

Tags: discussion

> **Seeing as people want hats, we're signed up for hats. Yay! Visit [winterbash2014.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com) starting December 15 for hat awesomeness.**
>
> If you absolutely hate hats, there'll be a button in the footer to turn them off.

Original post below:

---

Last year, Stack Exchange ran [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), in which users earned hats which they proudly displayed upon their avatar. There was a leaderboard of hat earners:

[image]

We have the option to do it again this year!

So, here's the rundown:

- Hats are enabled on a per-site basis, if we don't want them we can disable them here
- Hats are awesome, kinda like ephemeral badges
- Users can turn off hats on a per-user basis, so if you're a hataphobe you don't have to see everyone else having fun.
- If we choose to accept, the event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. After the time period, all the hats go away into Last Year's Hat Bin.
- We need to decide if we want hats by **December 1**

So, do we like hats or hate hats?

Comment: I don't want to waste time with hats.  But I can't downvote, because that requires 125 rep.  The system is rigged.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I want hats, they sound awesome and will keep my ears warm.

Comment: Hats, hats! They protect us against that ugly stuff falling out of the skies these days! :) So the more, the sooner, and the longer – the better #D

Comment: Especially you as a dog need a hat to protect your ears :)

Answer (score -7):

We are a community comprised of anti-hat software people, so we don't want hats.

Comment: Nah, we don't hate hats. We *had* hats on our heads in the past on other sites. I wish we had had more hats on our heads...